# Unlock movement/edit of internal polygon layers in altium 19?

Tags: altium, layout, polygon

I changed an internal plane to a signal layer and now I want to be able to move objects in this layers like polygon, however I seem to be unable to do so.

How can I unlock polygon move/edit in this layer?
There seem to be no "unlock/lock" like it's for components under properties.

Comment: Do you have the internal layers set up as planes or signal layers? For planes you need to move the primitives outlining the different plane sections.

Comment: @DerStrom8 I've the internal layers set up as signal layers.

Comment: I just realized I missed the first half of your first sentence =P

Comment: What version of Altium are you using? Could you please post a screenshot of you actively trying to move the objects?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you changed the layer within the layer stack manager. Usually this is a rather seldom step, which may cause some unexpected parameter shifts in the back-end of Altium.

Hence, to be on the safe side I suggest the following procedure;

1. First I would add a new signal layer.
2. Copy the polygons primitives, or even better use "Tool->Create from Primitives" to produce a fresh polygon on the new layer.
3. Finally delete the old plane layer.